# Workflow that sets values on a list, based on another list

Tags: workflow

I have two lists:

- UserRequests
- Access Profiles

"UserRequests" have a field "Access Profile" that connects to another list.
How can I feed my list "UserRequests" with values from "Access Profiles" ??

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint you have a column type called "Lookup" which allows you to **reference** items/item values from another list.

You cannot "feed" your list per say, but you can tell an item in one list to reference an item from another list.

So e.g. if you create a new item in UserRequests, you can reference an item from Access Profile in your UserRequests item.